# Vue JS 2 data manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

I have an instance of mounted in Vue, where I'm trying to set a date picker having the starting date depends on a data fed by an ajax response. Let's say this data property is named `start_date`. I run my ajax request via the created instance in Vue.

It's a little weird when I tried to console log vm.myObject, it shows the correct value `start_date` property coming from the ajax response. However, whenever I access the specific property via `vm.myObject.start_date` it will show you the default one I've created for data binding. My code structure below:

```
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    const vm = this;
    console.log(vm.myObject); // this will show the data from ajax response

    console.log(vm.myObject.start_date); //this will show the default value I set which si the 2017-10-25
  },
  created() {
    const self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: ApiRoutes.paths.GetDealData,
      data: { id: 1 },
      success: function(res) {
        self.myObject.start_date = res.start_date;
      }
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      myObject: { start_date: "2017-10-25" }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

I'm very new to Vue JS, so I'm currently having a hard time handling the data in the component via ajax request. I've already tried all the instances included beforeCreate, beforeMount but it didn't fix my issue still. How can I understand this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can't really work the way you described in your answer.
you are doing asynchronous operation (ajax call) and try to print the values right after  synchronous operation? nope.

If you want to `console.log(response)` , you can do it in your callback function.

If you want to print the value on the page, but show nothing until the value is fetched (asynchronous operation), you can define on your `data` an attribute that signal if the fectching process is finished or not. and toggle it inside your callback.

I have edited the code to show how to declare the `date-picker` (have to be declared from the `template` side.

You have to pass the `start_date` as a props (I assume the prop name for the `date-picker` is `start-date`). when the ajax request is finished, the reactivity of vue will take care of re-rendering of the `date-picker`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <datePicker :start-date="myObject.start_date" />
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
  created() {
    $.ajax({
      url: ApiRoutes.paths.GetDealData,
      data: { id: 1 },
      success: function(res) {
        self.myObject.start_date = res.start_date;
        self.isFetchedFinished = true
      }
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      startDate: ''
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I'm actually trying to declare a datepicker using the start_date from the ajax response, however, the datepicker start date is not of the ajax response but the default that i set, console logging it is just part of my debugging

Comment: oh, I see, ill try your proposed solution. I actually did try that kind of way passing the data from the ajax response to my child component from the parent via prop. Didn't think that it might also be a fix to my datepicker issue. Thanks again!

Comment: However, is this the only way I can fix this? hmmm will it not really going work from the mounted instance? like just by doing `$('.start').datepicker({startDate: vm.myObject.start_date})`? since going back to my original question, console logging the data object will show the start_date ajax response but console logging the start_date property from the data object will show the default? Since if you think of it, the data is already there in the data object when you first console log it but when accessing the specific property of the data object it shows the default one?

Comment: im not sure why you are sticking to direct dom access with jquery. it's not the pattern of vuejs. if you are trying to use jquery datepicker, i suggest you find vuejs date-picker components. look at `vue-awesome` repository at github.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `console.log()` working before AJAX response is returned, so `console.log(vm.myObject.start_date)` prints unchanging string with initial value. However, `console.log(vm.myObject)` prints your object, which then changes, and you can see actual property value in browser console.

Example:

```js
var obj = { "name": "oldName" };
console.log(obj);
obj.name = "newName";
```

If you want a "frozen" version of your object, you can create a copy for logging:

`console.log(Object.assign({}, vm.myObject));`

Also, instead `self.myObject.start_date = res.start_date;` you probably want to use `this.$set(this.myObject, 'start_date', res.start_date);` for [change tracking](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

Comment: Thanks! However, console logging is just part of my debugging, I'm actually assigning the value to a datepicker where I can also replicate the issue. I will trying the setter method if that could fix my problem